# Uniformly Lebesgue differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis

*Note: Here $\mu$ denotes Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.*

We say a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is *uniformly Lebesgue differentiable* if there exists some measurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb R$ with $\mu(E^c) = 0$ such that the following holds:

> For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in E$ and all $0 < r \leq \delta$, we have
> $$\frac{1}{2r} \int_{B_r(x)} |f(y) - f(x)| \, dy < \varepsilon.$$

**Question:** Is it true that $f$ admits a uniformly continuous representative if and only if it is uniformly Lebesgue differentiable?

*Remark: The “only if” direction is clear, the “if” direction is the issue.*

Comment: You mean $dy$, right?

Comment: Ye, my bad. Corrected.

Comment: Perhaps discussion in second answer and its comments  can be helpful https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84661/can-l2-be-represented-as-a-space-of-functions-not-equivalence-classes

Comment: I unfortunately don’t see the connection of the second answer to this question.

Comment: I think they are basically saying that the average-ball operator gives the continuous representatives only if we already that that the function has such a representative. That is the only-if you talked about. I meant to the say the answer by Piere D'Ancona.

Comment: Hm, do we know that the average ball operator here gives a continuous representative?

Comment: That's what he claims in his answer only when we know to have existence of the representative. So I suppose in practice if you have a concrete f in my mind, his advice is to work with that operator and prove/disprove that it is continuous.

Comment: @WillieWong: Note that "uniformly continuous on every compact subset" is just another way of saying "continuous" :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  Suppose $f$ is uniformly Lebesgue differentiable (ULD).

Let's first note that $f$ at least has a *continuous* representative, since the functions $f_r(x) = \frac{1}{2r} \int_{B_r(x)} f(y)\,dy$ are each continuous (by dominated convergence if you like), and by the triangle inequality and the ULD condition, they are uniformly Cauchy and converge a.e. to $f$.  Therefore we can replace $f$ by its continuous representative, disregard the null set $E^c$, and assume that the ULD condition holds for all $x$.

Now the idea is that the ULD condition implies that $f(y)$ must be close to $f(x)$ for "most" $y \in B_r(x)$.  If $x_1, x_2$ are sufficiently close, then $B_r(x_1), B_r(x_2)$ have a lot of overlap, and so "most" of the $y$ in their intersection have $f(y)$ close to both $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$, so they are close to each other.

To make this precise, let $c$ be a small constant <s>to be chosen later</s> less than $\frac{1}{8}$.  Now fix $\epsilon > 0$, and fix an $r$ so small that $\frac{1}{2r} \int_{B_r(x)} |f(y)-f(x)| \,dy < c \epsilon$ for all $x$.  For arbitrary $x$, let
$$
A(x) = \left\{ y \in B_r(x) : |f(y) - f(x)| \ge \frac{\epsilon}{2}\right\}
$$
then by Markov's inequality
$$
m(A(x)) \le \frac{2}{\epsilon} \int_{B_r(x)} |f(y) - f(x)|\,dy < \frac{2}{\epsilon} \cdot 2r \cdot c \epsilon = 4 c r.$$

Now suppose $|x_1 -x_2| < r$.  Then we have $m(B_r(x_1) \cap B_r(x_2)) > (2-|x_1-x_2|)r > r$.  On the other hand, $m(A(x_1) \cup A(x_2)) \le 8cr$.  So <s>if we choose</s> since we chose $c < \frac{1}{8}$, then we have
$$m\left[(B_r(x_1) \cap B_r(x_2)) \setminus (A(x_1) \cup A(x_2))\right] \ge r - 8cr > 0$$
and hence this set is nonempty, so contains some $y$.  We have $y \in B_r(x_1) \setminus A(x_1)$ which means that $|f(y) - f(x_1)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and similarly $|f(y) - f(x_2)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, so that $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Very nice! Note that the existence of a continuous representative for $f$ from the a.e. uniform convergence of the $f_r$ is not quite immediate, but is not that difficult to prove true either.

Comment: @NateRiver: I just thought of it as: the $f_r$ are uniformly Cauchy on $E$, so since they are continuous, they are actually uniformly Cauchy on $\mathbb{R}$ (because $\sup_{\mathbb{R}} |f_r - f_s| = \sup_{E} |f_r - f_s|$ as $|f_r - f_s|$ is continuous).  So they converge uniformly to some continuous function $\bar{f}$.  On the other hand they converge a.e. to $f$ (on $E$), so we must have $f = \bar{f}$ a.e.

Comment: Oh yes, that is easier than what I had in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a completely elementary version of Nate's proof. (I was trying too hard to be fancy with how to use the overlaps; and Nate's proof made it clear the simplest way works.)

**Step 1**: It suffices to show that $f|_{E}$ is uniformly continuous, since $E$ is full measure and hence dense, and uniformly continuous functions on dense sets  have uniformly continuous extension.

**Step 2**: let $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ be given as in the uniform Lebesgue differentiability definition. Suppose $x_1, x_2 \in E$ is such that $|x_1 - x_2| < \delta$. WLOG assume $x_1 < x_2$. This gives

$$ |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \leq |f(x_1) - f(y)| + |f(x_2) - f(y) | $$

for any $y$ by triangle inequality. Average the right hand side over the interval $I = (x_2 - \delta, x_1 + \delta) = B_\delta(x_1) \cap B_\delta(x_1)$, we find

$$ \begin{align} |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| &\leq \frac{1}{x_1 - x_2 + 2\delta} \int_{I} |f(x_1) - f(y)| + f(x_2 - f(y)| ~ dy\newline & \leq \frac{1}{\delta} \int_{B_\delta(x_1)} |f(x_1) - f(y)| ~dy + \frac{1}{\delta} \int_{B_{\delta}(x_2)} |f(x_2) - f(y)| ~dy \newline & < 4 \epsilon\end{align}$$

---

Further remark: it is not necessary that $E$ has full measure. You just need that $E$ is dense.

When $E$ is dense, the above argument shows that there exists a uniformly continuous function $g$ such that $f|_E = g|_E$.

Let $x$ be a Lebesgue point of $f$. Let $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ be as in the definition of uniform Lebesgue differentiation (with the understanding that $E$ is merely dense, not necessarily full measure). The density of $E$ means that there exists a sequence of points $y_i \in B_\delta(x)\cap E$ and a sequence of radii $0< r_i \leq \delta$ such that $B_\delta(x) \setminus \cup_i B_{r_i}(y_i)$ has zero measure and the balls $B_{r_i}(y_i)$ are pairwise disjoint.

This shows
$$ \int_{B_{\delta}(x)} f = \sum \int_{B_{r_i}(y_i)} f $$
This sum can be estimated using uniform Lebesgue differentiability
$$ \left| \sum \int_{B_{r_i}(y_i)} f - \sum 2r_i f(y_i) \right| \leq 2 \delta \epsilon $$
On the other hand, we have $f(y_i) = g(y_i)$ and our earlier proof shows that $|g(y_i) - g(x)| < 4 \epsilon $, and hence
$$ \left| \int_{B_{\delta}(x)} f - g(x) \right| \leq 10 \delta \epsilon $$

Since $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$, by setting $\epsilon$ small, this shows that $ f(x) = g(x)$.

So we conclude:

**Theorem**: If $f$ is locally integrable, and for a dense set $E$ we have that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that for all $r\in (0,\delta]$ and all $x\in E$ the inequality $\int_{B_r(x)} |f(x) - f(y)| ~dy \leq 2r \epsilon$ holds, then $f$ is a.e. equal to a uniformly continuous function.